# Code for calculating a given math function in java - some suggestions

Tags: java, arrays, math, matrix, sum

I have to write a Java method that calculates this math function:
[image]
The function itself is not a problem but I need some advice.

C(u, v) is a two-dimensional array where I will save the result.

f(x, y) is a two-dimensional array from where I get the values I need to calculate C(u, v)

Obviously, I have to assume that the lengths of u and v are different (same for x and y). So, although the two summations are x = 0 to N-1 and y = 0 to N-1 (which would suggest that the matrix is the same size), I think it would be better to treat it as if it had different sizes.
So :

- x will be the lines (and I will find them with matrix.length)
- y will be the columns (and I will find them with matrix [i].lenth)
- (the two points above will also be reflected on the dimensions of the matrix C)
- 2N will be the total number of elements in the matrix

Did I think it right?

Comment: There's no reason to assume that the ranges of `u` and `v` are the same, so `C` may well not be square.  But the formula clearly states that `x` and `y` both range from `0` to `N-1`.  In other words, there are `N*N` values to add up for each pair of `u` and `v`.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be right, except for the 2N part,
2N is not the total number of elements, if the matrix has is N by M size then the total number of elements is N*M.
since it says on the equation (2N)then it probably means (N+M) or it could be (2N) or (2M), you need to be sure.